# pragma pack(n) vs pragma pack(push,n)

Tags: c, gcc, pragma, pragma-pack

What is the difference between

1. `pragma pack(n)` and `pragma pack(push,n)`
2. `#pragma pack(pop)` and `#pragma pack()`

Can someone explain through an example ? Which should be used when ?

I went through [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html#:~:text=%23pragma%20pack(push%5B%2C,and%20removes%20that%20stack%20entry)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html#:%7E:text=%23pragma%20pack(push%5B%2C,and%20removes%20that%20stack%20entry)) already but looking out for more explanation.

Comment: from an initial reading, ```pack(n)``` sets the alignment, while ```pack(push)``` pushes the current alignment on the stack. optionally can be restored through ```pack(pop)``` later on.

Comment: With push/pop you can write code that restores the previous setting without knowing what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `push` and `pop`, you can "stack" multiple packing specifications. Without, you can just return to the default:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct pushed_default {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct pushed_2 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct pushed_1 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct pushed_4 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
struct popped_a {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
struct popped_b {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
struct popped_c {
    char c;
    long l;
};

#pragma pack(2)
struct pack_2 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(1)
struct pack_1 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack(4)
struct pack_4 {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack()
struct pack_a {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack()
struct pack_b {
    char c;
    long l;
};
#pragma pack()
struct pack_c {
    char c;
    long l;
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n\n", offsetof(struct pushed_default, l));

    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pushed_2, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pushed_1, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pushed_4, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct popped_a, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct popped_b, l));
    printf("%zu\n\n", offsetof(struct popped_c, l));

    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_2, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_1, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_4, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_a, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_b, l));
    printf("%zu\n", offsetof(struct pack_c, l));
}
```

The result talks for itself:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wpedantic packed.c -O3 -s -o packed
$ ./packed 
8

2
1
4
1
2
8

2
1
4
8
8
8
```

You can use `push` and `pop` all the time. Especially you can `#include` headers with these directives without fear of breaking other pack adjustments.

This is the relevant part of the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html):

> 3. `#pragma pack(push[,n])` pushes the current alignment setting on an internal stack and then optionally sets the new alignment.
> 4. `#pragma pack(pop)` restores the alignment setting to the one saved at the top of the internal stack (and removes that stack entry). Note that `#pragma pack([n])` does not influence this internal stack; thus it is possible to have `#pragma pack(push)` followed by multiple `#pragma pack(n)` instances and finalized by a single `#pragma pack(pop)`.

Unfortunately the maximum number of pushes is not documented. However, in practice you will not reach it.

Comment: >Unfortunately the maximum number of pushes is not documented. However, in practice you will not reach it.

That would depend on the internal stack size ?

Comment: @CoolCamel Since it is the compiler currently running and regarding the packing, it is the limiting one. However, it is not the size of its execution stack. Instead it uses an internal data structure for the former pack values. I'm sure there are multiple stacks in the compiler. Look at this like you would use a stack in your program: It is completely independent of the execution stack. And you could implement it any way you see fit, as an array of fixed size, a linked list, ... And so the compiler's developer did, but without documenting it on the linked page.

Comment: Note that the alignment remains set for all declarations until explicitly restored with `#pragma pack([pop])`. This behavior isn't illustrated in this example, but it significantly contrasts with other compilers' behaviors using decorative attributes like `__attribute__((__packed__))` and `__packed`